# How to Abort Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I don't know why this is not working - it's driving me nuts...

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
procedure InitializeWizard();

begin
  { Custom wizard pages }
  CreateTheWizardPages;

  if ListBox.items.count < 1 then begin 
    MsgBox('No File Found:'#13#10#13#10 + 'For help visit: {#myWWW}', mbInformation, mb_Ok);
    Abort;
  end else

  { Custom controls }
  CreateAboutButtonAndURLLabel(WizardForm, WizardForm.CancelButton);

  { Custom beveled label }
  WizardForm.BeveledLabel.Caption := ' My Program ';

end;
```

The msgbox displays - but the installer does not seem to exit silently :-(

Answer (score 2):

Gah - so it turns out the code above works perfectly, just have to run it with the debugger turned off.

Hope this helps someone out there.  The abort statement is used to exit the installer but only works from certain fuctions / procedures.

Cheers,

Comment: There's no need to run your script without debugger. Just debugger (by default; it can be changed in the IDE settings) informs you about the exception you raised (by calling `Abort`) with the error message box. Btw., consider moving your check into the `InitializeSetup` event which saves the time and resources used to create the wizard form and provides much cleaner mechanism to abort the setup (since you don't need to use a visual control to hold a list of files; you can use `TStringList` which you can `Assign` to your list box `Items` after it's created).

Comment: Hi TLama - thanks for the tip.  Will do.  Sorry for slow follow-up, was OS when I asked this one.  Cheers

Comment: BTW, I had not come across the de-bugger settings... not sure how to mark your contribution as an answer...

Comment: Don't worry about that; feel free to include the info about the debugger's exception message boxes into your answer ;) About the *"Pause on exceptions"* debugger option (which is turned on by default); I would strongly recommend you to keep it on since it indicates a line which raised an exception, and that's very useful tool. You just need to remember that all the exceptions raised by your setup will be indicated by a message box in debugger (and that `Abort` raises an exception).